# Remove substring/pattern word from a string

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, preg-replace

Hi I have a large string in php varying from 100-10,000+ characters.

Within that string there may or may not be a substring of the form:

```
reference: asdas_ad_12321_3asd
```

if this substring exists, `reference:` will always be present but the size of the reference code may vary. The reference code is composed of letters, numbers, and underscores. The reference code may or may not end in a full stop,space or new line.

What is the best way of removing this substring from my string? Any pregmatch, or regular expression would help as I understand it but am not that good with it.

I'm guessing something like

```
preg_replace('/reference: [a-zA-Z0-9_]/', '', $string)
```

I'm I on the right track with this?

Comment: It seems that the regex you're attempting to match is `reference: [^ ]*`

Comment: "The reference code may or may not end in a full stop,space or new line." is not a helpful statement.  It would be better to define how it does end.  Perhaps it ends with something that is NOT a letter, number or underscore.

Comment: yea sorry I know what you mean. I wasn't sure if that would be helpful or not but thought I'd mention it just in case. When you're stuck on a problem you always think in the most logical manner :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're fairly close. But `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` just matches a single character listed in `[ and ]`.

You can use:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('/reference: [a-zA-Z0-9_]+/', '', $string);
```

Quantifier `+` matches 1 or more of the preceding regex pattern.

Or better:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('/reference: \w+/', '', $string);
```

Since `\w` is same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

[**Recommended Regex Refrence**](http://regular-expressions.info)

Comment: Sweet thanks @anubhava works perfectly, I was starting to answer my own question the more I broke it down. But it didn't quite work so I needed some help :)